# local rails engine running server but not console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

An application can start the Thin web server

```
rails s
```

However, launching the console

```
rails c
```

hangs and never returns to a prompt.

Obviously, I need it to run!
*note 1: I believe this is a consequence of an external disk that houses the application, that lost its connection to the main computer*
*note 2: I had read incidentally that the spring gem has some un-robust behaviours. Could this be a motive?*

Comment: Do you get any error  ? i mean when you run application , do you get any error ?

Comment: Run command `spring stop` & check again

Comment: @Salil.  That is correct.  console now starts.  Please post an answer so that this may be voted and referenced in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run following command & it should be fix

```
spring stop
```